# Scala Function Chaining and handle failure

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have many functions in my code defined with return type as `Either[Throwable, String]` and all of them have one argument of type `String`. Three representative functions of my code are defined as:

```
  val f1 = (input: String) => {
    /* Processing from the input using a library in my actual code returns a Either[Throwable, String] */
    if (input == "a") Left(new Exception(input))
    else Right("Success")
  }

  val f2 = (input: String) => {
    if (input == "b") Left(new Exception(input))
    else Right("Success")
  }

  val f3 = (input: String) => {
    if (input == "c") Left(new Exception(input))
    else Right("Success")
  }
```

To chain the function outputs, I'm writing code like:

```
  def x(input: String) = f1(input) match {
    case Left(value) => Left(value)
    case Right(_) => f2(input) match {
      case Left(value) => Left(value)
      case Right(_) => f3(input)
    } 
  }
```

Since this is just three functions so this might look like a short code. However there are multiple such `match`es that are happening in my code, so it's a very long code. I am looking to avoid such a chaining.

I know that Scala has a way to chain functions like `f1.andThen(f2).andThen(f3)`, however the problem is that in each `andThen` we need to pass the same argument, in this case being `input`. However I want to chain these functions so that if there is a `Left` output, it should not go to the next `andThen`.

I believe this can be simplified using Functional Programming, but I don't know where to start. Is there a way we can achieve this using Scala functional programming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have **cats** in scope, then all you need to do is this:

```scala
import cats.syntax.all._

val functions: List[String => Either[Throwable, Unit]] = List(
  // put your functions here.
)

val result: Either[Throwable, Unit] =
  functions.traverse_(f => f(input))
```

Otherwise, you may emulate it using this:

```scala
val init: Either[Throwable, Unit] = Right(())

functions.foldLeft(init) {
  case (acc, f) =>
    acc.flatMap(_ => f(input))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The second one helped. I didn't want to go with cats yet because we are already struggling with a huge JAR size after assembly.
This is going to allow me to do a lot of automation with our so many variable inputs in place..

Comment: @Sparker0i glad it helped, about JAR size, I just will say I have been there and done that; worst decision ever. By the time I said okay I will add **cats** just for this little function I realized I could apply it in so many places that I removed a lot of custom and poorly tested logic, it was also my final motivation to go nuts with **cats-effect** and I will never regret that but that is another story and there are way bigger considerations. - Anyways, all that to say, check **cats**, even if just for yourself, I am sure you are going to love it :)

Comment: Sure. Thanks for the heads-up Luis..